# Sumar los valores de una columna

Tags: javascript, json, array, reactjs, table

Tengo el siguiente array

```
array = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "Price": 100,
            "Item": {"id": 1, Name: "A"},
            "Date": {"id": 1, Start: "202001"}
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "Price": 200,
            "Item": {"id": 1, Name: "A"},
            "Date": {"id": 2, Start: "202002"}
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "Price": 300,
            "Item": {"id": 3, Name: "B"},
            "Date": {"id": 2, Start: "202002"}
        }
]
```

Y quiero poder sumar los valores para un dado periodo, como se muestra en la tabla:

| ITEM | 202002 | 202003 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| B |  | 300 | 300 |
| TOTAL | 100 | 500 | 600 |

Para un dado periodo lo siguiente funciona:

```
var aHolder = 0;
for(var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
   if(array[i].Date.Start === '202002') {
     aHolder = aHolder + array[i].Price;
   }
}
console.log(aHolder);
```

Necesito armar un array con los resultados para cada periodo.

Alguna sugerencia? Gracias!

Comment: y como mostras la tabla?

Comment: Hola! Quiero calcular esos valores aparte y luego mostrarlos en un div. Cada fila es un div, porque tuve que crear una función para agrupar los items y fue la forma que encontré para hacerlo. Ahora e inconveniente está en la suma de las columnas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inicializamos una variable donde almenamos un array con un un objeto inicial, allí introduciremos la suma de los valores de `Price` correspondiente a cada valor de `Start`.
Recorremos el array de entrada por medio de un ciclo `for-in` donde realizamos una condición de tipo `if-else` consultando si el array `amount` contiene un valor igual a `Start` de `array`.

De ser varadero suma el valor que ya contiene `amount` con el valores de `array` que esta siendo iterado en ese momento.

De ser Falso crea el objeto con el valores de `Price`.

```js
const array = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "Price": 100,
            "Item": {"id": 1, Name: "A"},
            "Date": {"id": 1, Start: "202001"}
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "Price": 200,
            "Item": {"id": 1, Name: "A"},
            "Date": {"id": 2, Start: "202002"}
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "Price": 300,
            "Item": {"id": 3, Name: "B"},
            "Date": {"id": 2, Start: "202002"}
        }
]

let amount = [{all_total_price : 0, Element: []}]
for (const i in array) {
  if ((amount.some(e => e.Start === array[i].Date.Start ))) { 
   const index = amount.findIndex(x => x.Start === array[i].Date.Start);
   amount[index].total_price += array[i].Price
   amount[index].Element.push(array[i].Price)
  } else {
  amount.push({Start : array[i].Date.Start, Element : [array[i].Price], total_price : array[i].Price})
  }
   amount[0].all_total_price += array[i].Price
   amount[0].Element.push(array[i].Price)
}

console.log(amount)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfectamente!

Answer (score 2):

Corregi mi resputesta justo despues de publicarla, creo que esto podria ayudarte no se si quede claro pero es algo muy sencillo

```js
let arreglo = array = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "Price": 100,
            "Item": {"id": 1, Name: "A"},
            "Date": {"id": 1, Start: "202001"}
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "Price": 200,
            "Item": {"id": 1, Name: "A"},
            "Date": {"id": 2, Start: "202002"}
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "Price": 300,
            "Item": {"id": 3, Name: "B"},
            "Date": {"id": 2, Start: "202002"}
        }
]

arreglo.forEach(function(arreglo, index) {});
console.log()
let suma1 = 0;
let suma2 = 0;

for(i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++){
  if(arreglo[i].Date.Start === "202001"){
    suma1 = arreglo[i].Price + suma1;
  }else if (arreglo[i].Date.Start === "202002"){
    suma2 = arreglo[i].Price + suma2;
  }
}
console.log('Suma para el rango 202001: '+suma1)
console.log('Suma para el rango 202002: '+suma2)
```

Comment: Considera leer [answer], edita y explica como esto soluciona el problema del OP

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu respuesta. Es útil.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar la siguiente función [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;

// 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
// expected output: 10

// 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
// expected output: 15
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la sugerencia. La cuestión es que la armé por filas por la complejidad del array, tenía que agrupar los demás valores para un mismo item. Cómo usar esas funciones para array distintos? En este caso hay que sumar solo los del mismo periodo.